# Doubt about Zemanim

Tags: zemanim, safek

There are several things that cannot be performed before Shekiah, and several things that cannot be done after. (For instance, one cannot daven Mincha after Shekiah.)

What if one is unsure if Shekiah has passed or not? Do we follow the general rules of Safek d'Oraisa L'Chumra and Safek d'Rabbanan l'Kula? Or do we say that we're always machmir? Or perhaps always meikel?

(I'm not asking specifically in regard to Shekiah. The question could be asked to any Zman; I just picked Shekiah as an example.)

Comment: ספק חשיכה ספק אינה חשיכה...

Comment: @DoubleAA That's what that refers to? I always understood that to refer to Bein HaShemashos.

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: @DoubleAA Perhaps even according to those (e.g. the Mechaber) who hold that you can count sefira already after sunset, you need to know for sure that the sun has actually set.

Comment: There is a Tosfos Yishanim in Yoma that deals with this.

Comment: 5th perek of Pesachim also does.

Comment: one can daven mincha until tzeis hacochavim

Comment: @Laser123 Really? I did not realize that.